# Detect Is userAccount Enable or disable in win xp or 7 + C#

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-2.0

How can i programmically Detect Is userAccount Enable or disable in local OS like win xp or 7 (not Active directory). in C#
also how detect userAccount pass is Expire or not? in C#

thanks.

Comment: You mean at the time of windows logging?

Comment: Why would you even have an account like that?  These are domain controller features.

Comment: no in a stanalone application.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static bool IsUserEnable(string username, ContextType type)
        {
            PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(type);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);

            return user.Enabled.Value;
        }
```

---

call this method like:

```
IsUserEnable("guest", ContextType.Machine);
```